What is this 4 element monoid?
My monoid has element set $\mathbb{M}=\{0,I,A,B\}.$ Here $I$ is the identity.
Multiplication $*$ works so $I * x = x * I=x,$ and $0* x = x * 0 = 0$ for all $x.$
Also $A*B = B * A =0$ and $A*A = A$ and $B * B = B.$
My question is, is there a well known monoid in the literature which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{M}$ ?

fwiw, Intuitively I see this as multiplication under modulo 6 where A = {3}, and B = {2,4}.

This is a semilattice. It is isomorphic to the power set of a two element set $X$ where $0=\emptyset$, $I=X$, and $A$, $B$ correspond to the two singletons. The monoid operation is intersection. Equivalently, swap $0$ and $I$ and use union as the monoid operation.
In general, a commutative semigroup in which all elements are idempotent, $x^2=x$ for all $x$, is a semilattice. All such semigroups arise from partially ordered sets under the operation of $xy:=\sup\{x,y\}$.

Joshua Tilley has given one nice concise description, but here’s another: It’s the multiplicative monoid of the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$, and more generally of the subset $\{(0,0),(1,1),(1,0),(0,1)\} \subseteq R \times S$ for any rings $R$, $S$.

Edit: Originally I meant to keep it short and sweet, but a couple of bigger points seem worth adding.
Firstly: Once you know a bit of ring theory/commutative algebra, this monoid is very recognisable.  As the notation suggests, elements 1 and 0 with the properties you describe (1 as an identity, 0 as absorbing) typically arise from the 1 and 0 of a ring under multiplication.  Then the properties you give for $a$ and $b$ say that they’re idempotent ($a^2 = a$) and orthogonal ($ab = ba = 0$).  These are “famous” properties of elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in a product ring (or more generally, they could be $(1,0,0,0,0…)$ and $(0,1,0,0,…)$ in a bigger product $R_1 \times R_2 \times \cdots \times R_n$).  If a ring element $e \in R$ is idempotent, then $(1-e)$ is idempotent and orthogonal to it (check these!), and $R$ must be isomorphic to the product $eR \times (1-e)R$ (a good exercise).  Generally one can show that idempotents in a ring correspond precisely to binary product decompositions of it, and collections of orthogonal idempotents correspond to independent factors in larger product decompositions.
In algebraic geometry, where $R$ is viewed as a ring of functions on some space $X$, then a product splitting $R = R_1 \times R_2$ corresponds to a disconnected partition of the space as two disjoint clopen sets $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ (since a function on $X$ consists just of independent functions on the two components); idempotents correspond to functions that are 1 on some clopen set and 0 on its complement, and so correspond precisely to clopen sets of the space; and orthogonal idempotents correspond to disjoint clopen sets.  So orthogonal idempotents in the ring $R$ let you recognise the clopen subsets of the space $X$, and hence its connected components.
Secondly: Joshua Tilley’s description of your monoid as the power-set of a two-element set connects to my description as $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$ in wider generality.  For any set $X$, $(\mathcal{P}(X), X, \cap) \cong ((\mathbb{Z}/2)^X,1,\times))$.  Exercise: under this isomorphism, what operation on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ corresponds to addition on $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^X$?

This monoid is indeed well known. Let $N$ be the monoid $\{0, 1\}$ under the usual multiplication of integers. Then $M$ is isomorphic to $N \times N$. In more details, the elements $A$ and $B$ correspond to the idempotents $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ of $N \times N$.
